# I can't see AD Recycle Bin in new DC?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I've a Server 2012 DC which is some services became malfunctioned. I've created secondary DC and moved all FSMO role to new one but I can't see AD Recycle bin in new server, when I right click to domain name at ADAC it seems "Enable Recycle Bin" option is greyed out. I can still access Recycle bin in old server. Is there any way to see it in new DC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Enable Recycle Bin" option is grayed out because it's already enabled.

The AD Recycle Bin is a forest level feature, which means that once it is enabled it is enabled forest wide. You don't need to enable it on every Domain Controller in the forest or domain. You enable it once per forest.